Definition of the $L^{1}$ seminorm on a manifold
I am currently reading Vector Analysis by Janich, and I am perplexed by this exercise:
EXERCISE 5.3. Let $M$ be an oriented $n$-dimensional manifold. As an analogue to $\| \cdot \|_{1,1}$ on $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n, \mu)$, how would a seminorm $\|\cdot\|_{1,1}$ need to be defined on the vector space $L^1(M)$ of integrable $n$-forms on $M$?
For each $\omega \in L^1(M)$, define an $n$-form $|\omega|$ such that $\|\omega\| := \int_M |\omega|$ determines a seminorm that is zero exactly on the forms that vanish almost everywhere.
I initially thought the answer would be to define the seminorm as the absolute value of $|\omega_p|$, but this was deemed wrong in the hint section. The answer still involves the choice of $\pm |\omega_p|$, but how exactly? Moreover, how should I prove that $|\omega|$ is integrable for all $\omega$ in $L^{1}(M)$?
If you're wondering how $L^1(M)$ was defined without the norm $|\cdot|_1$, I'm not sure either. However, I think it was defined locally, i.e. $\omega$ is integrable if there exists a decomposition in charts $\{(\varphi_i, U_i)\}_i$ such that
$$
\sum_i \int_{U_i} |\omega^{1, \dots, n}| dx < \infty.
$$
It seemed reasonable to define $|\omega|$ this way: given a positively oriented chart $(U, \varphi)$, we define
$$
|\omega|_p :=  
\begin{cases} 
\omega_p& \text{if} \quad \omega_p(\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n) \geq 0, \\
-\omega_p& \text{if} \quad \omega_p(\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n) \leq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
How else should I proceed?

The $n$-forms are basically equal to functions.

your last definition doesn’t make sense; you shouldn’t evaluate the $\omega_p$ on $\partial_1,\dots,\partial_n$. It should just read $|\omega|p=+\omega_p$ if $\omega_p(\partial_1,\dots,\partial_n)\geq 0$, and likewise in the other case. Another way of expressing this is that if $\mu$ is a volume form corresponding to the orientation of $M$, then $\omega=f{\omega}\cdot\mu$ for a unique function $f_{\omega}$. Define the $n$-form $|\omega|:=|f_{\omega}|\cdot\mu$. Verify this is still integrable (it reduces to the simple fact that absolute value of absolute value is just the absolute value).

@peak-a-book I believe there is still some confusion in your last comment. You mentioned that I should not evaluate $\omega_p$ on $\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n$, yet in the following sentence, you wrote $\omega_p(\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n)$. This seems contradictory.

how about I just edit your post

@peek-a-boo thanks, but do you have any clue about why the author stated that is wrong to define $\vert \omega \vert$ as $\vert \omega_p \vert$ ?

Because it is not a differential form . It is not multilinear, nor is it alternating (how can it be, it has absolute values). If you define it with absolute values like that, you’ll end up with a scalar density, which is also a perfectly fine object, and in fact it is the correct thing thing to integrate on a manifold (oriented or not).

@peek-a-boo, is the last definition I provided different from just taking the absolute value at every point? If so, how? Is this last definition the correct way to define the $L^1$  seminorm?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
